# Есть ли для java профилировщик, который может подключаться к уже работающему процессу?

Tags: jboss, java-ee, профилирование, java, jvm

Есть .war веб-приложение. Проблема в том, что через несколько дней работы на сервере оно начинает тормозить. А если сервере перезагрузить то опять начинает быстро работать. Есть ли для Java EE такие инструменты с помощью которых можно было бы подключиться к JVM и посмотреть с какими вычислительными ресурсами возникает проблема. Может быть где-то происходит утечка память или еще что-нибудь. Как это можно определить на работающем приложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно есть. Вот к примеру [подборка](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2012/09/java-memory-model-simplified.html). Я лично работал с [mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Он позволяет анализировать дамп памяти процесса (при этом этот дамп можно и отдельно снять, а анализировать у себя на машине). Вначале инструмент выглядит странно, но потом, наловчившись, можно даже смотреть отдельные поля нужных объектов или узнать, сколько объектов заданного типа создано. Более того, он даже может подсказать, где может быть утечка.

Answer (score 2):

Есть стандартный Java VisualVM (см. исполняемый файл jvisualvm в $JAVA_HOME/bin). Сам по себе он не сильно функционален, но помогает анализировать дампы памяти (heap dump) и потоков (thread dump).

Судя по симптомам либо нагружается GC и есть утечки памяти, либо своевременно не освобождаются другие ресурсы. Можно например снимать дампы памяти (см. утилиту jmap) через определенные промежутки времени, а затем анализировать их в поисках проблем.

Есть ключи JVM, которые позволяют получать дополнительную информацию о работе GC. Например такой набор ключей:

```
-verbose:gc -Xloggc:file -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamp -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

заставит JVM писать в файл информацию о каждом запуске GC с выводом времени запуска и дополнительной информацией об областях памяти.

Также есть платные и довольно функциональные профайлеры: например YourKit Profiler и JProbe.